# Regex match the first occurence relative to the occurence of another pattern

Tags: java, regex

I have a json from which I need to replace the entire parameter if the placeholder value is not found.
For eg -

> {  "A": {      |"B": "{0}",|       |"C": "{1}",|       |"D": "{2}"|}};

In this json if the replacement for placeholder 1 is not found, i would like to remove

> |"C": "{1}",|

When I use this regex -
`(\|.*)(\{1}",\|)`

The previous parameter is also matched -

> |"B": "{0}",|      |"C": "{1}",|

How do I use a lazy version of the same to get the desired result?
Thanks

Comment: Be careful about asking [XY problems](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) on Stack Overflow.  This is where your problem is X, and you think you have the correct solution Y, so you ask about Y instead of asking "how do I solve X"?  Your question, "How do I use a lazy version" seems to imply that you've already decided that a lazy quantifier is the solution--but it isn't.  If there's some specific reason you need a lazy quantifier (e.g. your professor said you had to), you need to explain why; otherwise, you're just asking the wrong question.

Comment: Sorry! You re right.. I was wrong about assuming what the solution could be

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming I understand the problem correctly: A lazy (or reluctant) quantifier (i.e. using `.*?` instead of `.*`) won't give you what you want.  This is because the pattern matching still goes from left to right.  So when the matcher sees the first `|`, it will then find the smallest number of characters it can until it finds the next `{1}`.  Since it's a reluctant quantifier, it will look for the smallest number of characters it can before it finds `{1}`, rather than the largest.  But that doesn't help you, because it's still searching from the wrong initial `|`.

The solution here is to realize that the match can't have any `|` in it other than the first and last characters.  So instead of `.*`, use a pattern that excludes `|`:

```
(\|[^|]*)(\{1}",\|)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer sir